# How to show pop-up messages after LongClick

Tags: android, popup, onlongclicklistener

I'm new to Android and wonder how could I show a user a simple message after LongClick in one of the following buttons. The idea is to show the user the password he is using on each of the sites after a LongClick.

Any ideas?

```
public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
        setTitle("Main Menu");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void openWeb1(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ljmu.ac.uk/")));
    }

    public void openWeb2(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.bbc.co.uk")));
    }
    public void openWeb3(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com")));
    }

    public void openWeb4(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.adidas.com")));
    }

    public void openWeb5(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com")));
    }

    public void addNew(View v){

    }

}
The XML code:
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.androidbootcamp.myunimanager.MainMenu" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/btnLJMU"
            android1:layout_width="290dp"
            android1:layout_height="76dp"
            android1:drawableRight="@drawable/profile"
            android1:onClick="openWeb1"
            android1:text="Liverpool JMU" />
        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/btnBBC"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="76dp"
            android1:drawableRight="@drawable/contacts"
            android1:onClick="openWeb2"
            android1:text="BBC News" />
        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/btnFACEBOOK"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="76dp"
            android1:drawableRight="@drawable/courses"
            android1:onClick="openWeb3"
            android1:text="facebook" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnADIDAS"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/calendar"
            android1:onClick="openWeb4"
            android1:text="adidas" />
        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/btnSTACKOVERFLOW"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="76dp"
            android1:drawableRight="@drawable/notes"
            android1:onClick="openWeb5"
            android1:text="StackOverFlow" />
        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/btnADDNEW"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="78dp"
            android1:onClick="addNew"
            android1:drawableRight="@drawable/myuni"
            android1:text="Add New" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a LongClickListener for the button. Inside of it, you can execute the corresponding action by showing a pop up.

```
 button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Check the following to learn about how to create pop up messages.

Hope this helps!